# Usar findOne() do mongoose com condições

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

Preciso verificar se um usuário existe com base no e-mail e/ou no CPF dele.

Meu código atual é esse:

```js
if (
  (await User.findOne({ email: body.email })) ||
  (await User.findOne({ cpf: body.cpf })) ||
  (await User.findOne({ email: body.email, cpf: body.cpf }))
) {
  return res
    .status(400)
    .json({ status: "ERROR", message: "User already exist." });
}
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de reduzir essas 3 linhas de código com `await User.findOne()` para uma só ou para algum bloco de código mais legível.

Comment: Pode usar `$or` para checar as condições: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#with-a-query-specification

Answer (score 0):

Poderá resolver este impasse utilizando o operador **$or**, por exemplo:

```
if (await User.findOne({$or: [{email: body.email }, { cpf: body.cpf }, { email: body.email, cpf: body.cpf }]})) {
  return res
    .status(400)
    .json({ status: "ERROR", message: "User already exist." });
}
```

Podemos melhora o código escrevendo desta maneira:

```
const userExists = await User.findOne({$or: [{email: body.email }, { cpf: body.cpf }, { email: body.email}, {cpf: body.cpf }]})
  
if (userExists) {
   return res
    .status(400)
    .json({ status: "ERROR", message: "User already exist." });
}
```

Para mais infomações consulte a documentação: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#with-a-query-specification